# What is the right way ? With javascript and mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, object

I have a mysql table, named "cars", where I store : "brand", "model", "color". I would like to get the data like this :

```
[
    {
        brand: "audi",
        cars: [
            {
                "model": "coupe",
                "color": "red",
            },
            {
                "model": "a3",
                "color": "blue",
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        brand: "renault",
        cars: [
            {
                "model": "modus",
                "color": "white",
            },
            {
                "model": "clio",
                "color": "green",
            },
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

So, what I'm doing is a first mysql query where I group by brand, then I iterate the result to get all the cars for each brand :

```
const query = "SELECT brand FROM cars GROUP BY brand"
mysql.query(query, values, (err, result) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        const query2 = "SELECT model, color FROM cars WHERE brand = ?"
        const values2 = [result[i].brand]
        mysql.query(query2, values2, (err2, result2) => {
            result[i].cars = result2
            callback(result)
        })
    }
})
```

The code that I'm showing is working, but I don't think that doing an iteration for a mysql query is a good thing.

I've done a lot of research, and I don't really know what to do.

Is it possible to get this result with one single mysql query ? Or should I get all rows from the "cars" table and then do JS stuff to format the data ? Or should I continue using this mysql query iteration ?

Thank you

Comment: Why not using a json oriented database like MongoDB if you dont want to transform the data?

Comment: The question is whether you want to return raw data to the client or grouped data. It's not really matter of what is the best thing to do, it's rather about how the data is handled by who is requiring the data.

Comment: @MauriceNino I can't go with MongoDB .. I'm already running a web app with mysql, and I'm not complaining about that

Comment: @briosheje The data is required by the client, so I can do the transformations on server or client

Comment: Ok then there is your answer: No you cant get the result you want with one single query. Although you can get all the data and transform it in your JavaScript code. That way your Databse doesnt get that much traffic. But mysql is not capable of returning arrays. It has a function called `GROUP_CONCAT` but it gets messy really quick.

Comment: You can use :` "SELECT model, color FROM cars WHERE brand IN ('renault','bmw')"` and that group the entires in JS

Comment: @MauriceNino Thank you for your answer ! Can you show me a bit of code on how to do the trick ? Because I tried with Array.reduce() but I couldn't be able to get the data the way I wanted

Comment: @DJYadav Can you show me how to "group" is JS to get the same format of data as I'm showing on top ?

Comment: @FlorianPascouau Check the solution I posted below, It has the same thing as you asked: to group a array of objects, with brand.

Comment: @FlorianPascouau posted an answer for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick. Its client side transformation though:

```
let carArr = []

const query = "SELECT brand, model, color from cars"
mysql.query(query, values, (err, result) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        // Get the index of the brand in the carArr array
        let brandIndex = carArr.map(c => c.brand).indexOf(result.brand)

        // If the brand is not already in carArr, enter a new value for it
        if(brandIndex == -1)
            carArr.push({"brand": result.brand, "cars": [{"model": result.model, "color": result.color}]})

        // If the brand already exists, add the car type to this specific barnd
        else
            carArr[brandIndex].cars.push({"model": result.model, "color": result.color})
    }
})
```

Comment: No problem! If it helped you feel free to accept the answer. Thanks for making me aware of my issue (I actually blindcoded this)! Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
const carsByBrand=[],brands={};  
function find(){
 const query = "SELECT model, color FROM cars WHERE brand IN ('renault','bmw')"
 mysql.query(query, values, (err, result) => {
    /*assuming value  to be like: [
            {
              brand:audi,
                "model": "coupe",
                "color": "red",
            },
            ]
       */

  values.forEach((car)=>{
      if(brands[car.brand]){
        carsByBrand[brands[car.brand]].cars.push(car)
      }else{
        let index=carsByBrand.push({
          brand:car.brand,
          cars:[car]
        })
        brands[car.brand]=index;
      }
    })    
  }
 })

}
find()
```

Comment: I did not tried it, the other answer was good. But thank you for your very fast answer !

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve by single query itself by using `GROUP_CONCAT`,`CONCAT` mysql function.
once you got result cars key will JSON string. you can convert by using JSON.parse method

```
select brand,CONCAT("[",GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("{'model':'",model,"','color':'",color,"'}")),"]") as cars from cars GROUP BY brand;
```